# My pipeline is duplicating the same table in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

The following function is supposed to create a table in postgresql, but if I execute it with the same name in the ***SQL Script*** and ***df.to_sql('spotify'...)*** it freezes and does nothing, and when I change the name for either of the two statements, it creates 2 different tables in my db. Something is telling me I should not be creating 2 connections (*conn* * and *engine*) but I'm not sure about this.

I want to be able to create my own table to then append it to my df...

I'd highly appreciate some feedback.

```
def extraction():
    
    TOKEN = 'BQC1Cas7Nj6T61Gkq7ufKa2e6MKjNXjembypav0wsMuEVATyZSZRbgELPXR1i12Qzz8doLck1cueDIn-uqp0EcvyYeVHnFIEGb4MkCjgmIl8975UIDkCvP9WTBzUDHok1RmuQw6ySeHMkREuY-KtWm367yopkyBWQYuR28It'

    #We need headers to send the information along with our request, so this should be part of our request.
    headers = {
        "Accept":"application/json",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization":"Bearer {token}".format(token=TOKEN)
    }

    r = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played",headers = headers)
    response = r.json()

    if 'error' in response:
        print('The TOKEN is either wrong or has expired')
    else:
    #if my response went smoothly, then we proceed to extract and loop through my .json dictionary and get the values from it.
        my_song_list = []
        global df

        for song in response['items']:
            artist_id = song['track']['artists'][0]['id']
            artist_name = song['track']['artists'][0]['name']
            artist_link = song['track']['artists'][0]['external_urls']['spotify'] 
            album_id = song['track']['album']['id']
            album_name = song['track']['album']['name']
            album_link = song['track']['album']['external_urls']['spotify']
            song_id = song['track']['id']
            song_name = song['track']['name']
            song_link = song['track']['external_urls']['spotify']
            duration_ms = song['track']['duration_ms']
            popularity = song['track']['popularity']
            disc_number = song['track']['disc_number']
            played_at = song['played_at'].split(".")[0]
            
            song_dic = {'artist_id': artist_id,
                            'artist_name':artist_name,
                            'artist_link':artist_link,
                            'album_id':album_id,
                            'album_name':album_name,
                            'album_link':album_link,
                            'song_id':song_id,
                            'song_name':song_name,
                            'song_link':song_link,
                            'duration_ms':duration_ms,
                            'popularity':popularity,
                            'disc_number':disc_number,
                            'played_at':played_at
                            }
            
            my_song_list.append(song_dic) #now, in order to convert my DICTIONARY to a DATAFRAME, I should consider appending it to a LIST first.
            
            df = pd.DataFrame(my_song_list) #now that all my songs are in a LIST datatype, I can convert it to a dataframe.
            
    #This is a basic transformation performed in my dataframe:
        
    #Re-ordering columns in my df
    df = df[["artist_id","artist_link","album_id","album_name","album_link","song_id","song_name","song_link","duration_ms","popularity","disc_number","played_at"]]
    #Creating two columns (date, time) by spliting the played_at column.
    df[['date','time']] = df['played_at'].str.split('T',expand=True)
    # #Right now, played_at, date & time are objects, so we need to change these to timestamp.
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
    df['played_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['played_at'])
    df['played_at'] = df['played_at'].dt.tz_localize('US/Central')
    
    return df

def loading():
    
        
#psycopg2 is only used when connecting to a PostgreSQL Database, so we first make contact by setting some basic info.
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port='5432',dbname='Athenas',user='postgres',password='cis15a')
#Creating a cursor to display my PostgreSQL Version
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print('=============================================================')
    print('Connected to Athenas')
    print('PostgreSQL database version:')
    print("=============================================================")
    cur.execute('SELECT version()')
    db_version = cur.fetchone()
    print(db_version)

#Creating the "Spotify_API" table in PostgreSQL using the psycopg2 library.
    table_py = """        
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spotify(
        unique_identifier SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        artist_link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        album_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        album_name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
        album_link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        song_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        song_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        song_link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        duration INT NOT NULL,
        popularity INT NULL,
        disc_number INT NULL,
        played_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        date DATE NOT NULL,
        time TIME NOT NULL
        )
        """
#Executing my "table" using my cur variable.
    try:
        cur.execute(table_py)
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("All good")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred when initializing the database")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")
        print("=============================================================")

#In order to load my existing dataframe to the table we previously created using the psycopg2 library, 
#we now need to create an engine using SQLALCHEMY and APPEND my dataframe to the spotify_API Table.        
    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:cis15a@localhost:5432/Athenas')
    
    df.to_sql('spotify', con = engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
    print("=============================================================")
    print("=============================================================")
    print('The ETL ran succesfully')
    print("=============================================================")
    print("=============================================================")
    cur.close()
    
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute 2 times the create table statement:

```
cur.execute(table_py)
if cur.execute(table_py) == True:
```

What you wanted to do was:

```
try:
   cur.execute(table_py)
   print("All good")
except Exception as e:
   print("An error occurred when initializing the database")
```

Comment: you are right,I removed the duplicated line, but still, this is not solving my original issue....